# C++: How to construct object with two iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, construction

I have sample big integer class.
It contains dynamic array of digits that comprise the big integer.
I would like to construct objects of this class using 2 iterators (begin and end) in order I can pass digits from std::vector or std::list.

Some pseudocode illustrating my idea:

```
BigInteger(std::iterator begin, std::iterator end);
...
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// fill vector with digits
...
BigInteger b(v.begin(), v.end());
```

The question is: how to declare such constructor correctly?
Also even is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The same way `vector` does it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: so, there is no way to use some "common iterator type" ?

Comment: There is no "common iterator type". Consider that `int*` is a valid iterator.

Comment: @DaddyM there is no simple way, because there is no common iterator type. You would have to create one. It is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: I presume `v` is a vector of int or something similar.

Comment: @dionadar Yep. I understand that the simplest iterator is plain pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template constructor:

```
template<class InputIterator>
BigInteger( InputIterator begin, InputIterator end )
```

This should be used like:

```
std::vector<int> v; //Fill with values    
BigInteger( v.begin(), v.end() );
```

Comment: so, there is no way to use some "common iterator type" ?

Comment: do I need to use reference to iterator instead of just copying iterator object? Will it be possible and more efficient?

Comment: Well an InputIterator is a common iterator type. You could just use Iterator if you want as well.

A reference works but apparently it's common practice to use iteraters not by reference.

Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104035/generic-iterator-in-c

Answer (score 1):

**You can not use it simply!**

If you declare the iterator types as templates, you can have this:

```
template <typename Itr>
BigInteger(Itr begin, Itr end)
{
}
```

or

```
BigInteger(std::vector<int>::iterator begin, std::vector<int>::iterator end)
{
}
```

But, how about `std::iterator`. Well, `std::iterator` is a template class and you should provide it's parameters and you should derive from it

```
class MyItr : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
...
};

BigInteger(MyItr begin, MyItr end)
{
}
```

It's a long story! A possible definition of `std::iterator` is

```
  template<typename _Category, typename _Tp, typename _Distance = ptrdiff_t,
           typename _Pointer = _Tp*, typename _Reference = _Tp&>
    struct iterator
    {
      typedef _Category  iterator_category;
      typedef _Tp        value_type;
      typedef _Distance  difference_type;
      typedef _Pointer   pointer;
      typedef _Reference reference;
    };
```

As you can see, it's just an empty class with some `typedef`s. So, you have to implement `operator*()`, `operator->()`, `begin()`, `end()`, ... for derived iterator.

Comment: please tell me what should I implement instead of ... ?

Comment: @DaddyM: Using templates to pass the iterators are common and simple way. `std::iterator` is not a straight way, you have to override many members, it's just an empty class.