# Generic constructor using iterators

Tags: c++

I have a time series class `TimeSeries` and I need to be able to construct it from some dates and values. `Date` is a date class. I currently have this as the constructor:

`TimeSeries(std::vector<Date>::const_iterator dates, std::vector<double>::const_iterator values, std::size_t s)`

and I call it using `TimeSeries(dates.begin(), fixings.begin(), size)` where `dates` is `std::vector<Date>` and `fixings` is `std::vector<double>`.

But I'd like to adjust the constructor so I can use the C++ standard library way of just calling an iterator without reference to the underlying data type: `dates`, and `values` do not need to be iterators on `std::vector`.

Sadly I can't work out the constructor arguments. Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104035/generic-iterator-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Why not implement it "the C++ standard library way" too?

```
template<class DateIt, class ValueIt>
TimeSeries(DateIt dates, ValueIt values, std::size_t s)
{
    /*ToDo - your construction here*/
}
```

Then you can call it using `TimeSeries(dates.begin(), fixings.begin(), size)`.

My "inspiration" is taken from the way `std::max_element` works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to accept any iterator-like object. To fix the interface, it's usually a good idea to look for analogous behaviour in the standard library.

In this case, you want to iterate over two sequences, having the same number of elements, and do something with each one (namely, insert them into your time series). This sounds a lot like [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) in its two-sequence form:

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt,
          class BinaryOperation >
OutputIt transform( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, 
                    OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation binary_op );
```

You don't need users to be able to specify a binary operation; your constructor already knows what to do. You also don't want an output iterator, which just leaves the `begin,end` pair for the first sequence, and the `begin` iterator for the second sequence:

```
template <typename DateIterator, typename ValueIterator>
TimeSeries(DateIterator first, DateIterator last, ValueIterator first2);
```

This form requires only that the value sequence has at least as many elements as the range specified on the date sequence. In particular, the size is not explicitly given, so this form could be used with the more generic input iterator concept, rather than being restricted to forward iterators (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator for iterator categories).