# Is there any polymorphic wrapper for stl iterator from any container?

Tags: c++

I need a **virtual** function accepting `begin, end` input iterators as arguments but I don't want to tie it with a specific container's iterator class.
Is there anything in the standard (modern) C++ library that allows hiding specific iterator class from the client and behave as GenericInputIterator, GenericForwardIterator, etc? I suppose it should be sth polymorphic.

Comment: It may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104035/generic-iterator-in-c

Comment: TLDR: Nope, C++ does not work this way. There is nothing like that in the C++ library because the language doesn't work with it, on a fundamental level. Something is either a template, or a class. There is no such thing as a virtual template function, that's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There's nothing stopping you from writing a type-erased iterator class, which is what the question requires. It'll just be v e r y   s l o w. *That*'s why the standard library doesn't have one. Boost calls it `any_iterator`.

Comment: @HTNW - this is exactly what I'm talking about. So You say "no"...

Comment: There are plenty of articles in textbooks or online (e.g. by Scott Meyers) that explain why the C++ standard library does not provide such a "type-erased" or "generic" (another term I've seen used) iterator.  Essentially, such an iterator would be limited to only having operations that are supplied by ALL iterator types (most iterator types have some operations that are not shared by all other iterator types) and every operation supported by that iterator would have the worst-case performance for all possible iterators.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. What are you trying to do? Why aren't you erasing the entire range operation instead?

Answer (score 2):

There's none in the language.

There's one in boost, though  it's an implementation detail of [`any_range<>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html).

There are considerable performance costs involved, in fact often so much so that I'd advise against this in general. Very rarely you could use this to accept an erased range assuming that you're going to consume it in parts of the code that are not performance sensitive.